# Finding the right file path for a Perl file on a windows server?

Tags: perl, sql-server-2008

Using Cygwin on my local machine, the following Perl code works:

```
system "cmd /c start 'c:\\cygwin\\home\\fl\\CSmtp_prac.exe'";
```

when I try to move the Perl file on to Windows SQL server 2008, I can't get it to run.

It says it can't find it on the server even though it is indeed there and I have updated the path to do so. The icon of the perl file is of perl so I know the server has perl on it.  I'm wondering what is wrong with my syntax.

Here's what I have on the perl file that is on the server: system "cmd /c start 'c:\PDAutomation\CSmtp_prac.exe'";

Comment: I doubt you will get an answer to this question until you use a regular Perl script rather than a .exe file.   How are we supposed to know how you put that .exe together.  There are a thousand things you could have done wrong.

Comment: The .exe file runs on the local machine with the perl script.  I just want to transfer what works on the local machine to the server.  The perl script calls the .exe file.

Comment: ok, but even though you say that, the question is still not very clear.   for example, this question is much clearer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907494/running-a-batch-file-from-perl-activestate-perl-in-windows?rq=1

Comment: With an exe, you may not have bundled all the required dependencies. The exe would work on your build machine but, not on the deployed machine. perl -v output on each host to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the single quotes inside the `system` call. They are fine in Cygwin and the `bash` shell, but in the Windows shell it will look for filenames with a literal `'` character in them.

Try one of these instead, which should work in both Cygwin and MSWin32:

```
system 'cmd /c start c:\cygwin\home\fl\CSmtp_prac.exe';
system q(cmd /c start c:\cygwin\home\fl\CSmtp_prac.exe);
system "cmd /c start c:\\cygwin\\home\\fl\\CSmtp_prac.exe";
system qq(cmd /c start c:\\cygwin\\home\\fl\\CSmtp_prac.exe);
```